# Referencing a codebehind function from an ASPX page with a Namespace

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

I have a very unusual problem and would appreciate help. I have a web application in VS 2019.

I am trying to create a page that runs in its own namespace so I can share it with other websites. Below is a simple sample page and code.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="xxxx.test1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%= Myfunc1() %> 
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Namespace xxxx
    Public Class test1
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Public Function Myfunc1() As String
            Myfunc1 = "Hello"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The compilation shows  <%= Myfunc1() %>  as MyFunc1 not found.

If I remove the "Namespace xxxx" from the code behind and change the Inherits="xxxx.test1" to Inherits "TestWebsite.test1" (TestWebsite is the namespace for the web project and the default setting when you add the test page). This code compiles and works OK.

I would appreciate advice on how I can achive my aim of making the namespace for the page independent of the website project.

Thanks
Paul